# bigcommerce stencil: trying to add a custom Javascript module __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__common_firebase__.a._log is not a function

Tags: webpack, bigcommerce

## assets/js/theme/home.js (homepage)

```
import {firebaseFactory} from './common/firebase';
export default class Home extends PageManager {
    loaded(next) {
        console.log(firebaseFactory) //ƒ firebaseFactory(){_classCallCheck(this,firebaseFactory)}
        firebaseFactory._test('test'); //__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__common_firebase__.a._log is not a function
        next
    }
}
```

## assets/js/theme/common/firebase.js

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
export class firebaseFactory {
    init() {    
        var config = {...};
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
    _test(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    }
}
```

## Question

above in `home.js` I am trying to access functions from `./common/firebase` to be used like a service. If you look at what the console.log says above (commented out); Can you see what i am doing wrong? I am pretty sure i have to register the module with app.js or webpack but I have no idea how